# Extract arguments from a PHP function using Regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract do a mass replace across all my PHP files for the following string:

```
$var->getVar($lc['first_var']['second_var']);
```

to replace with:

```
$lc['second_var'];
```

I've spent a few hours trying to figure it out but I'm lost at this point.

The variables in 'second_var' is dynamic so it's fairly complex. Any ideas?

I can get the `$lc['first_var']['second_var']` using the following:

```
\(([^\)]+)\)
```

Now I just need to replace `['first_var']` so I get back `$lc['second_var']` - my thought process at this stage is to ignore `['first_var']` - is this possible, then I would have my solution?

Comment: Please add the latest attempt to see where the problem is.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew most of my attempts have come via generators as I don't understand Regex that well.

Comment: Can we see some realistic sample input and expected output from that input?  Let's see your failed attempts.

Comment: @mickmackusa please see my above comment.

Comment: We _need_ to see -- as a matter of principle.  We are not meant to provide a free coding service here.  Bad attempts are perfectly acceptable here.

Comment: Apologies @mickmackusa I've updated with my attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pattern [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zRdRIV/1)

In Notepad++:

Find what: `\$var->getVar\(\$lc\['[^']*'](\['[^']*'])\)`

Replace with: `\$lc$1`

- The backslashes are escaping characters with special meanings to the regex engine.
- The `[^']` is a negated character class that means "any character that is not a single quote".
- `*` means zero or more of something (as much as possible).
- `$1` in the replacement means "capture group 1" -- which is the second variable.

p.s. FYI, you don't need to add a slash to `)` when it is inside of your negated character class (from your attempt).

Comment: That's great, thank you very much! Do you have any good resources on Regex to learn it better?

Comment: http://regex101.com is a great, free, educational place to trial your patterns.  https://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a highly informative resource.  In all honesty, it just takes practice.  I also recommend watching the masters on StackOverflow -- Wiktor is always good value (go to his profile and troll through his regex answers, they always have explanations).

Comment: Thanks a lot @mickmackusa - that's really helpful!